# Prevent Access Form getting refreshed

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form where I used a textbox for the value adding and in the AfterUpdate a calculation value is put into other text box.

But the form gets refreshed and all textbox values become 0 or Null.

Please assist why its get refreshed. Is there way to stop getting form refreshed?

In a textbox AfterUpdate I just used the below code to add the values.

```
Dim avlqty As Integer
Dim prqty As Integer

avlqty = Me.availqty.Value
prqty = Me.purqty.Value

Me.availqty.Value = avlqty + prqty
Me.totalqty.Value = prqty
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have written seems to be recursive

```
If avlqty = Me.availqty.Value and Me.availqty.Value = avlqty + prqty Then
    Me.availqty.Value = Me.availqty.Value + prqty
End If
```